# HANA List all materials in 3rd level of a hierarchy

Tags: hana

Concerning Graphical Calculation view in HANA 1.0, I have two questions around using HANA modeling tools:

1. How can I **write a Graphical Calculation view that would give me all materials in a product hierarchy** of CN1003 and display the text description of CN1003 as well?

I know I can use MARA.PRDHA to get the hierarchy for a material and T179T to get the text for a hierarchy;  but it seems I need to generate a calculated column to just contain the first 6 characters then filter.  but best practices indicate to not filter on a calculated column.  So what's the right approach here?  Is there  a table I can join to which breaks the hierarchy down? so I can filter on the first two segments of 'CN' and '1003'?

For example:
MARA

```
+-------+--------------+
| MATNR |    PRDHA     |
+-------+--------------+
| 12345 | CN1003       |
| 12346 | CN10034231   |
| 12347 | CN1003423112 |
| 12348 | CN1002       |
| 12349 | FK1003       |
+-------+--------------+
```

T179T

```
+--------------+----------+
|    PRODH     |  VTEXT   |
+--------------+----------+
| CN1003       | Widgets  |
| CN1002       | Magnets  |
| CN10034231   | Tall     |
| CN1003423112 | Red      |
| FK1003       | Minerals |
+--------------+----------+
```

**Expected Results:**

```
+-------+---------+
| MATNR | VTEXT   |
+-------+---------+
| 12345 | Widgets |
| 12346 | Tall    |
| 12347 | Red     |
+-------+---------+
```

2. in a Graphical calculation view: what is the purpose of setting a semantic type of a varchar(8) field to date?  I thought this would cast the "date" varchar(8) field to a date datatype to be consumed by a Universe from the Calculation view;  but apparently not.  So Must I use a calculated column to convert this non-date date to an actual date datatype and isn't that against best pratices as again I'm filtering on a calculated column?  So how do I get my string date to a date to do this?  Or should I require my users enter a string date which seems like a bad UI choice in my reporting BI universe.

**Why doesn't HANA just store dates as dates!?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two well written questions - thanks for that.

For the **second question**, the answer is fairly straight forward: the semantic property of fields in calculation views is really just an indicator for the front-end tool to "do the right thing" with it. It's mostly used by SAP front-end tools and AFAIK not really broadly used by any other tool.

As for the date data storage: that's a SAP ABAP <s>idiosyncrasy</s> design decision that has been in place for many decades. It allows SAP ABAP to store date/time information on any supported DBMS with the guarantee to get back the data in exactly the same way with a clearly defined semantic. 
The ABAP data types are called `DATS` and `TIMS` and represent the date/time information in a character format.

If you want to enable filtering based on actual dates (or even on a hierarchy of date/time information), then the SAP tools (like SAC) support this out of the box. Alternatively, you can provide a value help view that performs the data type conversion ad-hoc for the selection and convert the filter condition back to the `DATS`/`TIMS` format.

That way, the conversion effort is minimal compared to the remaining query processing.

Concerning the **first question**, I'm not sure that I see the problem here.
Matching up the texts with the hierarchy identifiers can be done via a simple text-join (or a regular join). 
Your filtering can easily work on a value help view (again) based on the text table that presents the de-composed (pun intended) string parts to the end-user. 
Based on the selection, the join from the text-table to the parts-table will only include the selected records.

Again, the conversion effort is done only once on the smaller table (the table with the smaller dictionaries).

There is not hard and fast rule that states that you have to pre-compute every data transformation in SAP HANA. Quite the opposite is true. With the mentioned ad-hoc transformations in the value helper views, you can avoid needless conversion on large tables without additional pre-computed structures.

The other remark to this I can offer is that, in my experience, it really does not pay off to introduce pre-calculated columns and indexes before an actual performance issue had been identified.
It does, however, pay off to think about when, where and why data will be transformed and design accordingly.

Comment: Appreciate your time: and Pardon my ignorance here; but a value help view that decomposes the hierarchy must do so using calculated columns correct?  So am I not violating best practice by filtering on that calculated column from the value help view?  (Maybe I just don't understand what a value help view is though)

Comment: I keep re-reading this and gaining what I believe are better insights to your answer.  So based on the comment; "the conversion effort is done only once on smaller table"; I think you're saying it's ok to filter on a calculated column in this case; because we're not doing it on the whole transaction table but instead the T179 master data/config only.  That is then INNER joined to MARA for only those that are CN1003 and in this case the filter on a calculated column is the "Best practice"